# Oven Timer not Beeping

Tags: appliances, oven, timer

I have a [Whirlpool GR448LXPQ](http://www.whirlpool.com/-%5BGR448LXPQ%5D-1007628/GR448LXPQ/) Electric Oven/Stove.

When the timer is set, it counts down to 0, then shows `end`, but it doesn't beep.  The beeper, however, does work when pressing the buttons.  I was wondering whether there is something I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beeper may simply have been turned off. Try pressing and holding `COOK TIME` for 5 seconds to turn tones on, and `Snd ON` will appear on the display. (This is from the Owner Manual.)

Answer (score 1):

What I did was turn off the oven at the main fuse box, left it for a few minutes then switched it back on. The oven had reset itself and the beeper now works.

Answer (score 0):

I just pressed and held the clock setting button and followed instructions to set the beep. I had inadvertently turned it off previously when I changed the time from daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

my GE had the same problem not sure if it'll help. But I pushed the bake button then pushed the timer button without pressing the start button. by doing this the beeping sound came back. I did that by mistake just doing stuff and that worked for my oven timer to get it's sound back.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out! Since that sounds like it might be specific to your model of oven, you could consider posting a new question and checking the "share your knowledge, Q&A style" box so you can answer your own question.